# Typescript - Guard against intersection elements

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-generics

How can you make typescript warn on an element level if that array element is present in another array?

For example:

```
const canBeAorB = <A1 extends ("a" | "b")[]>(arr: A1) => arr

const arr0 = canBeAorB(["b", "c"]) // Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'.
```

This is what I want to achieve for TS to warn me on a element that it is invalid

But instead of a value I need to guard against all elements of other array, for example:

```
const blockedElements = ["a", "b"]

const myArr = ["b", "c"] // make TS yell that "b" is invalid because its a member of blockedElements
```

I managed to get really close by doing this:

```
const blockedValues = ["a", "b"] as const;

type BlockedElement = typeof blockedValues[number];

const cannotHaveBlockedEls = <A1 extends Readonly<Exclude<A1[number], BlockedElement>[]>>(arr: A1) => arr

const arr3 = cannotHaveBlockedEls(["b", "c"] as const)
```

Which will yield:

```
Argument of type 'readonly ["b", "c"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly "c"[]'.
  Type '"b" | "c"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
    Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"c"'
```

But the error is displayed on top of the whole array argument instead of on top of "b", my real use case is a larger array where this would really make a difference.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Are the blocked elements always going to be string literal types?  If so then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mb0x2w) work for you? If not, could you [edit] the example to show a use case that it doesn't satisfy?

Comment: yes they are always going to be string literals, your example works perfectly! thank you so much I've spent like 3hours+ on this

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you're running into is that the [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) in `["b", "c"] as const` effectively makes the whole expression opaque to the `cannotHaveBlockedEls()` function you're passing it into. It's as if you wrote this:

```
const oops = ["b", "c"] as const;
const arr3 = cannotHaveBlockedEls(oops);
//                                ~~~~ <-- error
```

Presumably the only reason you wrote `as const` there in the first place is to force the compiler to see `["b", "c"]` as an array of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) instead of just `string[]`.

If so, there are other ways to do that.  Here's one:

```
const cannotHaveBlockedEls = <T extends string>(arr: Exclude<T, BlockedElement>[]) => arr
```

The [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string`, which gives the compiler a hint that you'd like it to be inferred as a  string literal type (or a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string literal types).  Since `T` is now a `string`, we need `arr` to be of an array type whose element type is `Exclude<T, BlockedElement>`.

Of course this means that `arr` must be an array of strings or string literals.  If you needed to accept other types, you'd have to widen the constraint on `T`.

Anyway, let's see it in action:

```
const arr3 = cannotHaveBlockedEls(["b", "c"]); // error!
// ------------------------------> ~~~
// Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
```

Looks good!